# Syntax of a clause in Wikipedia's entry on "Irish Bulls"

Tags: syntax

What's the syntax of the clause in bold?

> **Extensive use of Irish bulls are made of by American Jewish humorists**,
>   from the period when large numbers of recent Jewish immigrants from
>   Germany or Eastern Europe were present in American cities, which
>   suggests that a similar effect produced the term "Irish bull", which
>   is partly contemptuous and partly homage.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Irish_bull&diff=904183422&oldid=874734596)

Comment: I take it you want the syntax of the expression in bold. It's a passive clause with the NP "extensive use of Irish bulls" as subject and the VP "is made of by American Jewish humourists" as predicate. Incidentally, the article you copied contains an error: the verb should be "is" not "are".

Comment: Please be aware that I've since edited the Wikipedia article.  This does not negate the question because A) my edits may be reverted, and B) its a good example of how bad writing is confusing to any reader.

Comment: @Andrew And the syntax that the OP seemingly asked for in his question "What is the syntax of this clause?

Comment: Simplifying, but retaining the relevant syntax, ***Use of humour is made of by comedians***. Which I'd say is just ***syntactic garbage***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: I've since edited the Wikipedia article so that it does not show your original text.  This does not negate your question, which I think is a good example of how poorly-written English can be confusing to any reader.*

It's an awkwardly phrased (and grammatically incorrect) *passive voice* version of

> American Jewish humorists **make** extensive use of Irish bulls

It's grammatically incorrect because the subject is "extensive use", which is singular, not plural.  So the verb should be "is".  It's awkward because the double preposition in "made of by" is clumsy, and this use of "made of" is easily confused with the use to indicate *composition*, as in:

> All of the floats in this parade **are** entirely **made of** flower petals.

As written in your question, it's run-on sentence badly needing to be edited.  A somewhat better version:

> American Jewish humorists have made extensive use of Irish bulls, dating from the period when large numbers of recent Jewish immigrants from Germany or Eastern Europe were present in American cities. This suggests that a similar effect produced the term "Irish bull", which is partly contemptuous and partly homage.

Side note:  The sentence is, I think, misleading.  The term "bull" is likely synonymous with (or perhaps just polite for) the term "bullshit", although in this case it's more of a "backwards compliment" than a pejorative.  We admire someone who can make a clever quip that is clearly nonsense but still full of meaning.  We aren't *contemptuous* of them.

Moreover, there there is no suggestion in the article that Jewish immigrants themselves called this "Irish" as a term of contempt.  It may be that Jewish humorists made phrases like this in English, just as they had done in whatever language they spoke before immigrating to the United States, and considered it a "Jewish" form of humor.

It's difficult to say for sure, as there has always been some friction between ethnic communities in densely-packed cosmopolitan cities like New York.  I'd need to research source material from the time.